# Need help, I broke my ubuntu user's login. Can't login

Tags: login

I'm a web developer so I was attempting to install php5/nginx for local developing. I'm not sure if either of these commands did it, as timing was not immediate, but I am no longer able to login to my main account(sending this message from ubuntu guest)

**recent CLI commands:**

```
sudo usermod -a -G www-data bngreer
sudo su bngreer
sudo subl /etc/nginx/sites-available/dev    +    ctr+c
```

(the latter seems to have crashed an open firefox instance also)

I'm not entirely sure how to check user login settings to see what can be fixed, I really would prefer not to erase and reinstall as I have some valuable data. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you seeing any error messages?  How far do you get when you try to log in?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, and [as such](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) is off-topic, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).